# Использование переменных в регулярке JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, match

Здравствуйте. Предположим есть такой шаблон, `a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_`. Его использую в регулярном выражении `match()`

Вот это полное регулярное выражение:

```
'AQwerty_083аСBlah-‌​Blah-Blah'.match(/[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_]/gi);
// оно вернёт: ["A", "Q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "_", "0", "8", "3", "а",
// "С", "B", "l", "a", "h", "-", "B", "l", "a", "h", "-", "B", "l", "a", "h"]
```

С этим никаких проблем нет. Дальше в специальной функции формируется шаблон, который возвращается примерно в таком вот виде: "a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9-_", в виде строки. Дальше я пытаюсь этот шаблон использовать в регулярке, примерно так:

```
var tmp_rg = tmp_rg('eng+rus+fig+-+_'); // "a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_"
var regexp = /[tmp_rg]/gi;
var matches = "AQwerty_083аСBlah-Blah-Blah".match(regexp);
// возвратит: ["r", "t", "_"], т.к. не воспринимает переменную
console.log(matches);
```

С этим мне ясно. А вот дальше я пытался переменную занести через `new RegExp(tmp, 'gi')` в саму регулярку. И написал это вот так:

```
var tmp_rg = tmp_rg('eng+rus+fig+-+_'); // "a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_"
var matches = "AQwerty_083аСBlah-Blah-Blah".match(new RegExp(tmp_rg, 'gi'));
// возвратит: null, ну а тут я не знаю в чем дело
console.log(matches);
```

Объясните мне люди знающие, почему так происходит? Почему не получается занести переменную в регулярку? Уже 2-ю неделю мучаюсь с этими регулярками.

Comment: `tmp_rg()` возвращает строку типа `[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_]` или сразу RegExp? Что-то неясно, как `'AQwerty_083аСBlah-Blah-Blah'.match(a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_);` вообще у Вас работает. Должно быть `'AQwerty_083аСBlah-Blah-Blah'.match(/[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_-]/g);`

Comment: возвращает: "a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_" вместе с кавычками

Comment: вообще не стоит присваивать значение функции переменной имя которой совпадает с именем функции: `var tmp_rg = tmp_rg('eng+rus+fig+-+_');`

Comment: @Grundy, если на функция на один раз, то ни всё ли равно? Хотя зачем тогда отдельную функцию делать...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, исправил, изначально было написано, как вы написали, вот так: `'AQwerty_083аСBlah-‌​Blah-Blah'.match(/[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_]/gi)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте конструктор для создания объекта `RegExp` из переменной:

```js
var tmp_rg = "a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\\-_";
var regexp = RegExp("[" + tmp_rg + "]", "gi");
var matches = "AQwerty_083аСBlah-Blah-Blah".match(regexp);
console.log(matches);
```

Заметьте, что знак `-` необязательно экранировать в данном месте или в начале или конце символьного класса, однако если впоследствии шаблон надо будет изменить, надежнее сохранить экранирование.

Символьный класс - `[...]` - находит 1 символ из определенных в нем наборов символов и диапазонов символов.

Comment: Как же просто и легко у Вас получается. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Легко, если в `tmp_rg` все диапазоны и символы указаны как надо, то что надо, экранировано (в коде с помощью двух обратных слешей). Символ подчёркивания `_` не нужно экранировать никогда и ни в одном из типов регулярок.

Comment: Я про другое, вам меньше 5 минут нужно было на решение этой задачи, а я над ней мучаюсь уже несколько дней. Регулярки для меня это страшный сон, к сожалению. 2-ю неделю не дают покоя.

Comment: Если знаете английский, можно быстро научиться основам на [RegexOne](http://regexone.com). На сайте MDN можно найти всё, что касается реализации регулярок в JS, а на SO вообще такие проблемы уже давно описаны.

Comment: С английским у меня проблемы. Простите за такой глупы вопрос, а что такое, `SO`?

Comment: Благодарю за ссылочку, буду исследовать по мере возможностей.

Comment: SO = StackOverflow. А вот ещё [ссылка на Викиучебник по регулярным выражениям](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Тестировать выражения легко на [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com), а для JS есть ещё [Regexr](http://regexr.com).

Comment: Виноват) Буду в курсе.

Answer (score 0):

С конструктором `RegExp` всё нормально, а вот регулярка некорректная.
Нужно сделать символьный класс - `[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-\_]`.

Comment: Делал, не помогает, т.к. шаблон возвращается в виде строки.

Comment: Ну и поправьте Вашу функцию чтобы возвращался символьный класс.

Comment: Поправил, изначально было так: `'AQwerty_083аСBlah-‌‌​​Blah-Blah'.match(/[a‌​-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\-_]‌​/gi)`